# win32 c++ I want to insert an EDIT control straight after the TEXT of the STATIC label

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hwnd

To make a STATIC label I can use:

```
            HWND hwnd_ques=CreateWindow(
                TEXT("STATIC"),
                TEXT("Yao happy swallow is"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                10,
                70,
                180,
                30,
                hwnd,
                NULL,
                (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
                NULL);
```

After calling `CreateWindow` I used `WM_SETFONT` msg to set the label's font and fontsize (which worked successfully):

```
            SendMessage(hwnd_ques, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font1, static_cast<LPARAM>(MAKELONG(TRUE, 0)));

//definition of font1 is not shown here but it worked successfully
```

However, I want to insert an EDIT control **straight after** the **TEXT** of the STATIC label, that is, I will make the label width fit its text width and assign the X POSITION of the EDIT according to the label position and width. if I specify the label width manually, it cannot make sure the **label width just EXACTLY fits the text width** because I don't actually know the **text width** of that label.

I wonder **how I can make the label width just EXACTLY fit its text width**. Perhaps I can **get the text width** since knowing the text content, font and fontsize. After **getting the text width** then I can turn back to set the label's width afterwards.

-

**PURPOSE**

I want to insert an EDIT control **straight after** the **TEXT** of the STATIC label

-

**EDIT**

Searched the Internet and it says to use **GetTextExtentPoint32**

```
SIZE textSize;
GetTextExtentPoint32(GetDC(hwnd), text, strlen(text), &textSize);
```

But where can I specify the font/fontsize in this function?

Comment: You'd have to write the code to measure the text of course.  This is not exactly conducive to a well-designed layout.  Consider solving the opposite problem, create the label to match the text box.  Very easy to do, you'd only have to align the text to the right.

Comment: @HansPassant Aligning the text to the right has no problem but it's not yet identical to what I need. I want to move the textbox according to the label, *with the left-side of the text of the label remaining at a known position.*

Comment: @HansPassant I actually need a way **how to measure the text**?

Comment: Just google "winapi measure text", too many hits to recommend any one in particular.

Comment: *Do not* mark a question as "solved" by editing the title or the body. *Do* mark a question as "solved" by *accepting an answer*. If there are no answers that work, make your own.

Comment: I've rolled back the last edit. Please add your own answer describing your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using function `GetTextExtentPoint32` like the following:

```cpp
SIZE textSize;
GetTextExtentPoint32(GetDC(hwnd), text, strlen(text), &textSize);
```

And by using `SelectFont` to specify the font before, this problem is solved.